# Unable to access Google Drive on Signed APK (Woking fine on debug-apk)

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm building an app which is integrated with google drive. I have followed all the procedure which is required to integrate Google Drive on my app.

And everything is working perfectly on signed-debug. but on signed-release apk, I'm able to login to Google. but unable to access google drive.

Even i have added signed apk SHA-1 in google developer console project and even the project has **../auth/drive.file** and **../auth/drive.appdata** scope.

This is the code which I use to create Credential in my app

`credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(MainActivity.this,Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE));`

On debug apk Crendential will be something like this `com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential@e172207`

On signed apk Crendential will be credential: `d.e.b.a.a.b.a.a.a.a@fb1faec` .

So basically everything working fine on signed-debug APK but not in signed-release APK even though I have followed the same procedure for both.
So Is there anything which I have to do differently for signed-release APK? So that I can access google drive from my signed-release APK.